# NSMachPort how to get the components

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsrunloop

So, I have an iOS 9 App that starts a NSOperation extended class and that class' main method it executes a NSRunLoop.  I also have implement handleMessage successfully, that is, when I send some parameters to the NSMachPort, it kind of works...

This is the sender:

```
NSMachPort *rcPort = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).rController.serverPort;
NSMutableArray *myarray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myarray addObject:@"hello"];

[rcPort sendBeforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture] msgid:666 components:myarray from:nil reserved:0];
```

My handleMessage does trigger, and I easily get the msgid

```
- (void)handleMachMessage:(void *)msg {

    NSLog(@"got a message");
    mach_msg_header_t *msg_t = msg;
    NSLog(@" %d ", msg_t->msgh_id);
}
```

My question is:

I do get the msgid (666), how do I get at the "components" part in handleMachMessage ?  I have searched high-and-low, and I cannot find any references or code samples.  It seems that handleMachMessage's msg parameter is only a mach_msg_header_t type, however, if I am able to add a "payload", why can't I get access to the said payload in my handleMachMessage?

Comment: Why don't you check the definition of `mach_msg_header_t`. If any additional information you get. Is the type casting from `void *`. Is it possible to cast it to other type.

Comment: Unfortunately, the header is all it is - a header...  This is mach_msg_header_t



typedef struct 
{
  mach_msg_bits_t msgh_bits;
  mach_msg_size_t msgh_size;
  mach_port_t  msgh_remote_port;
  mach_port_t  msgh_local_port;
  mach_port_name_t msgh_voucher_port;
  mach_msg_id_t  msgh_id;
} mach_msg_header_t;